# How can I sell a profile on magento?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, product

I want to build a magento virtual store, where i can sell profiles in a website community.
A profile is actually an account (identified with a unique code or password and username) where the user can fill some data, in my website community (the community is a separated platform, with a separated database).
How can i do that?
Is it possible to have a magento product like a unique code, that will be generated after the payment is done?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom module for this purposes, that will generate unique code (profile password) after purchase.